# PHP while array

Tags: php, while-loop

```
    if ($content = getData('LED'))
    {
        return $content;
    }
```

Need to go on line through the array until the content is not empty!
How?
Sry for bad english

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$airports = array('LED','DME','SVO','VKO','AER','KRR','IKT','KGP','KHV');
foreach($airports as $airport) {
  if($content = getData($airport)) {
    return $content;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like [array_walk](http://php.net/array_walk), [in_array](http://php.net/in_array), [foreach](http://php.net/foreach) or [array_reduce](http://php.net/array_reduce)?

Answer (score 0):

[foreach](http://php.net/foreach)

or [while](http://php.net/while), if you prefer